# How can I get the addresses who’ve interacted with an NFT contract? Need this to generate contract analytics

Tags: nft

I'm looking for a method to obtain the addresses of individuals who have interacted with a specific NFT contract. My goal is to generate contract analytics by identifying the users who have engaged with the NFT contract, such as buying, selling, or transferring NFTs. - elchuo160

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need to find a **source of data**. You can run your own archive node or use an API service (such as Etherscan or Alchemy). Let's assume you will use an API service as it is cheaper and easier to set up.

You will want to get **all historic transactions** for a given contract and then filter out those, which include a transfer event. This event is emitted for simple transfers, sells, buys,... If you also want to include different types of interactions (stake, unstake, setUri,...) then you just take all the transactions without filtering out any of them.

Now to get the addresses you want you can simply check who was the from address.